# XSL - Tokenize each line for split characters, issue with whitespace line not preserved

Tags: xml, string, xslt, line

I have below XML transformation code to tokenize each line in one of the XML tag and split when 64 characters per line is reached..

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fic="http://www.ba.com/schema/mes/FICOAccessV01">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="MessageContent" select="substring(/fic:FICOAccess/FICOAccessMessage/MessageContent,3)"/>
    <fic:FICOAccess>
        <FICOAccessMessage>
            <EncodingCharacterSetName>
                <xsl:value-of select="/fic:FICOAccess/FICOAccessMessage/EncodingCharacterSetName"/>
            </EncodingCharacterSetName>
            <MessageContent>
                <xsl:call-template name="splitBinaryData">
                    <xsl:with-param name="txt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$MessageContent"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </MessageContent>
        </FICOAccessMessage>
    </fic:FICOAccess>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="splitBinaryData">
    <xsl:param name="txt">
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="accum"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(concat($accum,$txt), '\n\r?')[.]">
        <xsl:variable name="temptxt">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($temptxt) &gt; 64 ">
                <xsl:call-template name="word-wrap">
                    <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$temptxt"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($temptxt, '&#10;')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="word-wrap">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:param name="line-length" select="65"/>
    <xsl:param name="line-ending" select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($str)&gt;=$line-length">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($str,0,$line-length)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$line-ending"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="word-wrap">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str,$line-length)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="line-length" select="$line-length"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="line-ending" select="$line-ending"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($str, '&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the input XML I am passing in,

**INPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fic:FICOAccess xmlns:fic="http://www.ba.com/schema/mes/FICOAccessV01">
<FICOAccessMessage>
    <EncodingCharacterSetName>ASCII</EncodingCharacterSetName>
    <MessageContent>NLKDAJLSJADKLJASASJSADKJSADSADLKAS;KDA;LKSAL;;    DS DASS DSAADSA DSAD
 ABCJDKSJKKSALKSJLALA
                                       DLASJDKADJKSAJKASDJKA
KSAHDJKSAHDJKSAHDJSHAJDHKSADHSAJDSAJKDSAHDJSAHDKJSAHDJKSAHDJ
DSA                S         DSS                  D  D  D  D







ASDDSA          FD   FDS     FDFSS          FSS  FD

BEV PX   N24    FF           CC/YY  101     WW         MM
    </MessageContent>
</FICOAccessMessage>
</fic:FICOAccess>
```

But the issue is, in the request I have blank lines in between and while tokenizing I am not able to preserve those lines and below is the response I am getting after transformation

**ACTUAL**

```
<fic:FICOAccess xmlns:fic="http://www.ba.com/schema/mes/FICOAccessV01">
<FICOAccessMessage>
      <EncodingCharacterSetName>ASCII</EncodingCharacterSetName>
      <MessageContent>NLKDAJLSJADKLJASASJSADKJSADSADLKAS;KDA;LKSAL;;    DS DASS DSDDSS
     ABCJDKSJKKSALKSJLALA
                                       DLASJDKADJKSAJKASDJKA
KSAHDJKSAHDJKSAHDJSHAJDHKSADHSAJDSAJKDSAHDJSAHDKJSAHDJKSAHDJ
DSA                S         DSS                  D  D  D  D
ASDDSA          FD   FDS     FDFSS          FSS  FD
BEV PX   N24    FF           CC/YY  101     WW         MM
        </MessageContent>
</FICOAccessMessage>
</fic:FICOAccess>
```

But below is the expected response

**EXPECTED**

```
<fic:FICOAccess xmlns:fic="http://www.ba.com/schema/mes/FICOAccessV01">
<FICOAccessMessage>
  <EncodingCharacterSetName>ASCII</EncodingCharacterSetName>
  <MessageContent>NLKDAJLSJADKLJASASJSADKJSADSADLKAS;KDA;LKSAL;;    DS DASS DSDDSS
 ABCJDKSJKKSALKSJLALA
                                       DLASJDKADJKSAJKASDJKA
KSAHDJKSAHDJKSAHDJSHAJDHKSADHSAJDSAJKDSAHDJSAHDKJSAHDJKSAHDJ
DSA                S         DSS                  D  D  D  D







ASDDSA          FD   FDS     FDFSS          FSS  FD

BEV PX   N24    FF           CC/YY  101     WW         MM
        </MessageContent>
   </FICOAccessMessage>
</fic:FICOAccess>
```

Any help with this is very much appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What processor are you using? I get the expected result when using Saxon 9.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for-each` `select` expression is `tokenize(concat($accum,$txt), '\n\r?')[.]`. The predicate `[.]` is the problem, since it removes all the zero length strings of the sequence (which you want to preserve), try removing it.